# Getting 404 when loading React component in a Laravel view

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I'm building a view in Laravel which is built using React and mix. It's served at `/admin`, and the controller and route is already set-up.

Here's how I do it:

#### `resources/views/admin/dashboard.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="admin"></div>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/components/Admin.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### `resources/js/app.js`

```js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes React and other helpers. It's a great starting point while
 * building robust, powerful web applications using React + Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh React component instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

require('./components/Example');
require('./components/Admin')
```

#### `resources/js/components/Admin.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function AdminView() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-md-8">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-header">Example Component</div>

                        <div className="card-body">I'm an example component!</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AdminView;

if (document.getElementById('admin')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<AdminView />, document.getElementById('admin'));
}
```

#### `webpack.mix.js`

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I already run `npm run serve` and `php artisan serve` but I always have this error:

`GET http://localhost:8000/js/components/Admin.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

How do I fix this? I'm completely unfamiliar with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to add *all* the React files into `webpack.mix.js`. So, it'd look like this:

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/components/component1.js')
    .js('resources/js/components/component2.js')
// Other components, views, etc goes here...
    .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

There may also be ways to programmatically include all other files in `resources/js`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your /routes/web.php
2. Change the code

   ```
   Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
   });
   ```

   to this

   ```
   Route::fallback(function() {
       return view('welcome');
   });
   ```